# mysql procedure succeed delete some date but return null as row_count()

Tags: mysql, procedure

It always return null when I executed  {select @leftnum,@deletenum ;},but it deleted the date as I excepted.sorry for pool English.

```
    delimiter //
    CREATE PROCEDURE  REMOVEandreturn3( IN NUM INT ,
                                         out leftnum int  ,
                                         out deletenum int)
    BEGIN
    DELETE FROM ORDERS2
    WHERE  ORDER_NUM = NUM ;
    select  count(order_num) 
    from orders2  into leftnum;
    select  row_count()  
    from orders2 into deletenum;
    END//
    delimiter ;
    call removeandreturn2  (20007,@leftnum,@deletenum);
    select *from orders2;
    select @leftnum,@deletenum ;
```